# При печати textarea оставляет пустое место

Tags: print, html, textarea, javascript

Нужно распечатать страницу, но поле textarea оставляет пустое место при печати. Как от этого избавится?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Map</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Printit() {
            document.getElementById('comment_text').innerHTML = document.getElementById('comment').value.replace(/(n|r)+/g, '<br>');
            print();
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        @media print {
            textarea {
                display: none;
            }
            input {
                display: none;
            }
            #comment_text {
                display: block;
            }
        }

        @media screen {
            input {
                display: block;
            }
            textarea {
                display: block;
            }
            #comment_text {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <table height="100%" border="0" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td height="100%" align="center">
                    <iframe width="600" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.ru/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=ru&amp;geocode=&amp;q=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0,+%D0%A3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0+%D0%93%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&amp;aq=1&amp;sll=55.639527,37.767906&amp;sspn=0.085162,0.264187&amp;vpsrc=0&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=%D1%83%D0%BB.+%D0%93%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0,+%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;ll=55.683072,37.7201&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
                    <br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span style="color:blue;"><b>Улица улица, 0</b></span><br/><br/>
                    <b>Коментарии:</b><br/>
                    <textarea rows="15" cols="70" name="comment" id="comment">test</textarea>
                    <input type="button" value="Печать" onClick="Printit();">
                    <div id="comment_text"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Добавлено**

```
function Printit()
{
document.getElementById('comment_text').innerHTML = 
document.getElementById('comment').value.replace(/(\n|\r)+/g, '<br>');
var textarea = document.getElementById('comment');
textarea.cols = '1';
textarea.rows = '1';  
print();
setTimeout("endPart()", 5000);
}

function endPart()
{
var textarea = document.getElementById('comment');
textarea.cols = '70';
textarea.rows = '15'; 
}
```

Comment: Для подсветки кода есть кнопочка 101010. @ХэшКод, может, ее назвать "КОД" или как-то более явно обозначить? По-моему, процент понимающих без наводки очень низкий.

Comment: Я нажимаю этот значок. У меня пишет вставить код тут. Вставляю, отображается в таком виде.

Comment: @Sh4dow Да, пожалуй, справку надо улучшать.

Comment: Sh4ow, тут же еще "сверхгениальная" система разделения блоков(ДаблЭнтером). Если просто нажать кнопочку на коде, который НЕ начинается с новой строки, он просто будет обрамлен в знаки ударения. =) Так что переименование кнопочки не спачет.

Comment: @knes, ник бы написали правильно - сработало бы ;)

@zoomka, на будущее, порядок: вставить код, выделить код, нажать кнопку.

Comment: А какой я символ неправильно написал?... Сейчас скопировал - правда сработало.  
Но разницы не вижу. Всегда писал ручками, всегда срабатывало...

Comment: Ты не написал 'd'.

Comment: вот [пример](http://trutee.ru/test3/) этой страницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я же сказал, что уже все сделал=)
Решение в 1 посте.

Заметил ошибку на вашем сайте, а именно:

Я могу преобразовать комментарий в ответ, хотя прав на это не имею.

Comment: Дашь автограф?

Answer (score 0):

Сдается мне, что это не textarea его оставляет, а `<table height="100%"...>` + `<td height="100%"...>` =) Уберите эти штуки, у вас таблица растягивается на весь экран, а ячейка с картой - на возможный максимум, потому вторая ячейка оказывается прижата к нижнему краю.

Comment: Не помогло. 
Возможно это связано с тем что я прячу textarea, но iframe не перестраивается.
Я пробовал изменять параметр cols и rows на 1 Все было хорошо.
Может это можно сделать как нибудь не посредственно перед печатью?

Comment: @ZoomKa Если бы вы что-то делали - помогло бы. [Пользуйтесь](http://sh4dow.jino.ru/test27.php), всего-то убрал `height="100%"`

Comment: Забыл уточнить, мне нужно чтоб он растягивался на всю страницу(

Добился нужного эффект путем изменения скрипта печати. Добавил в 1 пост.

Comment: Блин, вам нужно, чтобы на печати фрейм был во весь экран, а камент таки внизу?

Comment: Мне нужно было чтобы все отображалось на одном листе. И растягивалось на весь лист.

Comment: В общем, я игрался-игрался и кроме того, что фрейму какая-то рандомная высота на печати выставляется, ничего не выиграл =/ Будем ждать остальных. Там какая-то уличная магия, по-любому

Comment: Был ли этот баг уже известен?